# a4j:commandButton not working if not rendered on pageload

Tags: richfaces

My a4j:commandButton does not work if it has not been rendered when the page was loaded.
Try the following:

```
  <h:form>
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{showpnl}">
        <a4j:support event="onclick" reRender="pnl" />
    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>

    <a4j:outputPanel id="pnl">
        <a4j:outputPanel rendered="#{showpnl}">
            <h:inputText value="#{text}" />
            <a4j:commandButton value="Go" reRender="out" />
        </a4j:outputPanel>
    </a4j:outputPanel>

    <h:outputText id="out" value="Text: #{text}" />
</h:form>
```

It works if you set: `<a4j:outputPanel rendered="true">` on line 7 !!! Why?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure #{showpnl} evaluates to 'true' when the button is clicked. Otherwise, the button will not be processed.